# Template detection from array of templates OpenCV

Tags: objective-c, macos, image-processing, opencv, objective-c++

I've managed to set up OpenCV in my xcode project, and the first experiment was a success where I used OpenCV to match a template picture to a recent screenshot, and get the screen coordinates of that match.

If I had an array of images, say, different "x" boxes that I want my app to click, what would be the best way of doing so with OpenCV? Say, I have 4 images, "x1.jpg", "x2.jpg", "x3.jpg" and "x4.jpg", each of which is a similar but slightly different image (hence the 4 images).

Ideally I want my program to check if x1.jpg is visible in the current screenshot, if yes, return coordinates. If no, check if x2 is visible. And so on.

How would I do this?

Comment: What is the difference between the first case, in which you said you succeeded, and the current issue?

Comment: The first case is a function that takes a template, and tries to find it on a picture. 

Problem is if I want to identify which of my templates/images is currently on the picture. The above function takes a few seconds per template, so not really feasible to use with an array of templates. If you come up with anything for the above scenario, I'd be intrigued to hear more!