# Designing isImgVisible function for OpenCV?

Tags: objective-c, macos, image-processing, opencv, objective-c++

I'm using OpenCV to analyse screenshots made just before they're needed, and to allow my app to interact with a program.

In order for my app to know at what stage the target program is in, I was hoping to design an isImgVisible function through OpenCV, that would take an image as an argument, and would return a bool and screen coordinates of the provided image (if found on screen).

Is this doable? If so, how would you go about doing it?

Comment: You need to add more details, may be some images also. It is difficult to understand what you want to do.

Comment: possible duplicate of [template detection from array of templates OpenCV](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11284869/template-detection-from-array-of-templates-opencv)

Comment: I'm talking about template matching. So say I have a picture of a "add comment" button, and a picture of a "answer your question" button. I make a screenshot every few seconds, and I want to use OpenCV to recognise which of these two pictures is visible. I thought the best way of doing this might be to design a function that uses whatever aspects of OpenCV it requires to check whether it's argument (a reference to one of the pictures) is visible on the screenshot, and if so, to return a bool = YES and the coordinates of the image (probably through cv::minMaxLoc).

Comment: It's the less code-heavy image detection I'm wondering how to do, whether there is a faster way than using cv::matchTemplate.